# Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPack.VS Installshield

Tags: c#, installshield, powerpacks

I have a C# project, which installs via installShield express. When I install my app on other machines, I have Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPack.VS missing assembly issue.

How can I link powerpack to installshield express project> I am new at installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: In VisualStudio look for the reference name and click on it. Then in the properties panel set copy local to true. Rebuild project and installation project adn it solves problem.